# Reuse common bits of HTML Across Views in Kendo SPA via MVVM

Tags: mvvm, view, kendo-ui, single-page-application

I have some small bits of HTML that are used in nearly all of my views. I would like to be able to abstract these out of the views so that when I make changes to one view I don't have to update it in everyone of my views. I am not sure how to achieve this. I have tried the following via the MVVM declarative syntax.

```
<div id="toolbar" class="pull-right" data-role="view" data-template="edit-tool-bar">                                        </div>
```

But this doesn't do anything. I do not want to add code to push the HTML into the view if I can avoid this, that is the entire point of MVVM, right? I would be very thankful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard seems to be to use the `source` binding and specify a template. Since the main view is already bound to a VM telling I set the `source` binding to `this`.

```
<div id="toolbar" class="pull-right" data-bind="source: this" data-template="edit-tool-bar"></div>
```